# Using wildcards in between a C# DataTable Select statement

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to look for a pattern in a C# DataTable. I essentially have my code like:

```
long count= table.Select("Col0 LIKE '%AA%ZZ%'").Count();
```

However, I get an exception `System.Data.EvaluateException: Error in Like operator: the string pattern '%AA%ZZ%' is invalid`.

I read that wildcards can only be used at the beginning or the end in a C# select statement. Is there an alternative?

Ideally, I don't want to write a loop that goes through every row of the table myself.

Comment: check my answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491678/count-distinct-non-null-rows-in-a-datatable/37491900#37491900

Comment: there are plenty examples on line as well as `C# Stackoverflow` on how to use the `DataTable.Select` method along with wild cards also you are passing `TOO MANY % %` wild cards..

Comment: What do you mean by '%AA%ZZ%'? why extra % is placed in between?

Comment: @MethodMan Care to cite few links?

Comment: @MukeshAdhvaryu: I need a % in between since there could be other stuff between AA and ZZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to DataSet and regular expressions.

```
int count = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row =>
    {
        string value = row.Field<string>("Col0");
        return Regex.IsMatch(value, ".*AA.*ZZ.*");
    })
    .Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in how the string begins (that is, the `%` at the end), you can use this approach. Suppose you want this condition: `"LIKE 'Code02%'"`. For that, you could use:

```
long count = table.Select("Col0 >= 'Code02' AND Col0 < 'Code03'").Count();
```

This filter will return rows with values like `Code02`, `Code020`, `Code02AC`, `Code02ZZZZZZZ`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Since you explained that there could be other stuff between AA and ZZ you are trying '%AA%ZZ%' (which throws error), try this:

```
long count= table.Select("Col0 LIKE 'AA%' AND Col0 LIKE '%ZZ'").Count();
```

This will select each row where Col0 begins with "AA" and Ends with "ZZ" which means anything in between does not play any role.