# how do I count rows in a data table that is not null in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a data table with 2 columns in it, something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8MIU.png)

I would like to select the 2nd Column as a basis on the count of rows that is not null

Comment: When you say "data table", do you mean an RDBMS table (e.g, Access, SQL Server), or a `System.Data.DataTable` object?

Comment: System.Data.Datable

Comment: I have this at the moment

Comment: Dim dtDataTable As DataTable = io_Table
Dim row As DataRow

For Each row In dtDataTable.Rows
 out_RowCount = out_RowCount + 1
 
 Next

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count distinct non-null rows in a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491678/count-distinct-non-null-rows-in-a-datatable)